# Intercept Crashlytics data before upload

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting

Crashlytics Core for Android has a callback that is called after a crash occurred, during the next initialization:
[`CrashlyticsListener.crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution()`](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics-core/2.6.2/index.html)

But there is no way to edit the data of the crash before uploading it. I would like to edit this data before it gets uploaded. Is this possible?

It seems this is possible in iOS with [`- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void ( ^ ) ( BOOL submit ))completionHandler`](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Crashlytics/Protocols/CrashlyticsDelegate.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. It is not possible, on Android, to edit or change the report before submitting it.

Comment: Is it possible to get report id? (From string that logged as `Crashlytics report upload complete: ABCD-EFGG...`)

Comment: Not without using the debug mode of the SDK.